# SSRS Report run very slow after Database Upgrade

Tags: reporting-services

I have a sets of production report which run in less than one minute before . We have upgraded our databases and now those reports run in 45 minutes (at least) or never run and show dataset problem .
Should I change any other configuration after upgrading databases?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think this question is not programming-related and therefore [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Try [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) instead.

Comment: I agree with @Palec - given the thing that changed was the database and not the reports, it is not really a Reporting Services question, probably more a question for the [Database Administrators StackExchange site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ChrisLätta I thought about that one too, there is an overlap in scope between DBA and SF. But migration path from SO to DBA is not set up and it has a smaller community than SF.